# How to call list of functions with arguments?

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

How can I call a list of functions with arguments using list comprehension?

Comment: Is there any specific purpose in calling the list of functions with arguments using list comprehension?

Answer (score 4):

Like this

```
from math import sin, cos, tan

my_funcs = [sin, cos, tan]
results = [f(0) for f in my_funcs]
print(results)
```

Output

```
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: It is very inspiring and concise. Thanks.